# DataGridView with columns as strings AND columns as integers

Tags: vb.net

I have a datagridview with 5 columns (Venue, Location, Size, Capacity, Hire Cost).
I get the data from a text file. It all works fine except what i would like is for the user to be able to sort the capacity and hire cost by clicking on the column headers. The problem though is that because of the way it is coded all of the columns are strings. What i need is to have the first 3 columns as strings and the last two as integers, but i'm not sure how i should be modifying my code to achieve this.

I currently have the following:

```
Dim row As String() = New String() {vi.venue_name, vi.venue_location, vi.venue_size, String.Format("{0:n0}", vi.venue_capacity), "$" & String.Format("{0:n0}", vi.venue_hirecost)}
DataGridView1.Rows.Add(row)
```

How do i modify this so that only the first three columns are strings and vi.venue_capacity and vi.venue_hirecost columns are integers?

EDIT: I have sorted this. Was a very easy solution. I simply changed the line:
 `Dim row As String() = New String() {vi.venue_name, vi.venue_location, vi.venue_size, String.Format("{0:n0}", vi.venue_capacity), "$" & String.Format("{0:n0}", vi.venue_hirecost)}`
to:

```
 DataGridView1.Rows.Add(vi.venue_name, vi.venue_location, vi.venue_size, vi.venue_capacity, vi.venue_hirecost)`
```

It now works perfectly! :-)

Comment: Convert the values you load from the text file to a DataTable, where you define the data type of each column. Or use a Database instead of a text file.

Comment: How would i go about converting the values? The code i have to get the values from the text file are as follows: Dim lines() As String = IO.File.ReadAllLines("venues.txt")
        For Each line In lines
            If line.Trim.Equals("") Then Continue For
            Dim strArr() = line.Split(":")

            Dim vi As New VenueInfo()

            vi.venue_name = strArr(0)
            vi.venue_location = strArr(1)
            vi.venue_size = strArr(2)
            vi.venue_capacity = strArr(3)
            vi.venue_hirecost = strArr(4)

            VenueInfos.Add(vi)
        Next

Comment: A couple of thing: If you need to add new details or code, add them to your question (using the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54306064/edit) link), not in comments (btw, the code is missing pieces). Then, in a previous comment (another question ) I suggested (and probably others) to set **`Option Strict ON`**. Something you can't live without if you're dealing with Data and Data Types. Do that, correct the code in all the parts that need an *intervention* and update your question. IMO, any suggestion, at this point, will only generate new questions.

Comment: My apologies and thank you for the advice. I have sorted it on my own, as detailed in my original post.

Answer (score 1):

Better option will be using a datatable to do the same..Please read the comments in code  to understand what is done. Then bind the datatable to Datagridview..

```
''' <summary>
    ''' Sub for 
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    Public Sub GetData()

        ''Create a Dummy Datatable

        Dim tempCompoTable As DataTable = New DataTable()

        ''Add Columns
        tempCompoTable.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Venue", Type.GetType("System.String")))
        tempCompoTable.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Location", Type.GetType("System.String")))
        tempCompoTable.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Size", Type.GetType("System.String")))
        tempCompoTable.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Capacity", Type.GetType("System.Double")))
        tempCompoTable.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Hire", Type.GetType("System.Double")))
        tempCompoTable.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Cost", Type.GetType("System.Double")))


        Dim lines() As String = IO.File.ReadAllLines("venues.txt")
        For Each line In lines
            If Not line.Trim.Equals("") Then
                Dim strArr() = line.Split(":")

                ''Createnewrow
                Dim drworg As DataRowView = tempCompoTable.DefaultView.AddNew()
                drworg("Venue") = strArr(0)
                drworg("Location") = strArr(1)
                drworg("Size") = strArr(2)
                drworg("Capacity") = Val(Trim(strArr(3) & ""))
                drworg("Hire") = Val(Trim(strArr(4) & ""))
                drworg.EndEdit()

                ''if you want
                'Dim vi As New VenueInfo()
                'vi.venue_name = strArr(0)
                'vi.venue_location = strArr(1)
                'vi.venue_size = strArr(2)
                'vi.venue_capacity = strArr(3)
                'vi.venue_hirecost = strArr(4)


            End If
        Next

        grd.AllowUserToAddRows = False
        grd.DataSource = tempCompoTable

    End Sub
```

If you want instead of directly binding from array you can bind to value_info and then loopthrough it to add rows to datatable

Comment: Yes Sorry I didint checked it as of hurry..Will Update Answer

Comment: Thank you very much, i appreciate it. I have now found another solution, very easy.

Comment: Also, as a side not the pattern Trim(obj & “”) is a bit of left over VB6ism, and doesn’t do anything with .Net, where either implicit conversion (Option Strict Off) or an explicit conversion will happen before the call to Trim, and Trim never returns Nothing.

Answer (score 1):

I have sorted this. Was a very easy solution. I simply changed the line:

```
Dim row As String() = New String() {
    vi.venue_name, 
    vi.venue_location, 
    vi.venue_size, 
    String.Format("{0:n0}", 
    vi.venue_capacity), 
    "$" & String.Format("{0:n0}", 
    vi.venue_hirecost)
}
```

to:

```
DataGridView1.Rows.Add(
    vi.venue_name, 
    vi.venue_location, 
    vi.venue_size, 
    vi.venue_capacity, 
    vi.venue_hirecost
)
```

It now works perfectly! :-)

Comment: Well, it's a good thing if you can solve the problem yourself. I'm afraid this just solves the **immediate** problem. It will generate others along the road. Set `Option Strict ON` and use a DataTable built in code if you can't/won't use a Database. You'll understand why I'm saying this when you'll have to handle the Data.

Comment: You may need to play arround with Datagridviewcell incase you need some crud functionality or extra data related features..anyway.good that you solved the immediate problem..